# Dscriminant for a poynomial of degree higher than 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, factoring, discriminant

I am dealing with a polynomial of degree 5, which I want to prove is positive on a certain interval.

I found a statement on Wikipedia that exactly enable me to do this. There is no reference backing that statement. If anyone knows a reference (book or article) where that statement is proven and that I can cite, I would be grateful.

The statement is made for a real polynomial of degree 4 or higher on [that page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of Wikipedia: ``If the discriminant is positive, the number of non-real roots is a multiple of 4''.

All I need is a reference that I can cite for that result from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $\rho_{0},\dots,\rho_{\text{n}-1}$ the (a priori distinct, since we only care about the case in which the discriminant is nonvanishing) roots of the real (monic) polynomial $f$, WLOG ordered so that real roots precede nonreal roots and conjugate pairs are consecutive. Denote by $\text{disc}\left(f\right)\neq 0$ the discriminant of $f$.

By definition, $$\text{disc}\left(f\right)\ =\ \prod_{\text{i}_{0}<\text{i}_{1}} \left(\rho_{\text{i}_{1}}-\rho_{\text{i}_{0}}\right)^{2}\text{.}$$ Thus
\begin{align*}
    \text{disc}\left(f\right)>0\ \implies\ \prod_{\text{i}_{0}<\text{i}_{1}} \left(\rho_{\text{i}_{1}}-\rho_{\text{i}_{0}}\right)\ &=\ \overline{\prod_{\text{i}_{0}<\text{i}_{1}} \left(\rho_{\text{i}_{1}}-\rho_{\text{i}_{0}}\right)}\\
    &=\ \prod_{\text{i}_{0}<\text{i}_{1}} \left(\overline{\rho_{\text{i}_{1}}}-\overline{\rho_{\text{i}_{0}}}\right)\\
    &=\ \left(-1\right)^{s}\prod_{\text{i}_{0}<\text{i}_{1}} \left(\rho_{\text{i}_{1}}-\rho_{\text{i}_{0}}\right)
\end{align*} where $s$ denotes the number of conjugate *pairs* of nonreal roots. The claim immediately follows.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, given a polynomial of 5th degree with positive discriminant, is there a way to know if there are 0 or 4 complex roots?

Comment: @Gateauaufromage, not off of the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Thank you again anyway. I really appreciate the conciseness of your response! I learned a lot from a very small read.