# Quintic polynomial with positive discriminant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, discriminant, quintics

This is a sequel to [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857570/dscriminant-for-a-poynomial-of-degree-higher-than-3) where I learned why a real quintic polynomial with positive discriminant has either one or five distinct real roots.

As a followup, given such a polynomial (i.e. real, quintic, and positive discriminant), is there a criterion that enables one to determine which case it falls in between one or five distinct real roots.

Comment: Check out [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) which gives you the total number of real roots of the polynomial with real coefficients (not necessarily quintic or positive discriminant).

Comment: Hey, thanks. That looks really promising.

Comment: Hi again. I just wanted to thank you one more time. I did not know that theorem and I was able to use it in my case. Even found out that Maple has a built in function based on that theorem.